# Cannot Access Form Values With Python View in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to access the form values from a form that dynamically populates the number of input fields from a database query but I am not able to grab the values.

```py
def count_add(request):

    items = Item.objects.filter(username=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CountAddForm(request.POST)

        for item in items:
            print(request.POST[item])
            # if request.POST[item] != None:
            #     print(item)
            #     rating = form.save(commit=False)
            #     rating.username = request.user
            #     rating.item = item
            #     rating.date = datetime.now()
            #     rating.rating = request.POST[item]
            #     rating.save
            #     form = CountAddForm()

    return render(request, 'count_add.html', {'items': items})
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 opacity">
            <h4 class="card-title center-align white-text">Rate Your Items Below</h4>
            <form method="POST" class="center-align white-text"> {% csrf_token %}

                <ul class="center-align white-text">
                    {% for item in items %}
                    <li class="input-field col s12">
                        <select name="{{ item }}" class="browser-default">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>{{ item }}</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
```

My desire is to get a value back from the input fields and save them in the database. I get None back when I do actually retrieve a value currently.

EDIT:
I have tried using is_valid and cleaned_data[item] but it appears that the form never validates.

Answer (score 0):

Call `is_valid` then utilize `cleaned_data`:

```
def count_add(request):
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = CountAddForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: I should have noted that I tried is_valid before as well and can't get anything back from cleaned_data[item]. It appears the form never validates as I tried running a print statement from within the block and it didn't run.

Comment: Thanks Ivan but I am unsure where to access the errors. Could you provide a hint? I read through the document below but it appears to be for raising your own defined errors. I have also tried google seaching the issue and most are related to using forms classes. 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages